# Why does the pandas SettingWithCopyWarning not give exact location that caused the error?

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, warnings

Why is the `settingWithCopyWarning` is so imprecise about the causative line of code?

At best, the warning gives:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:<number>: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

The warning does give you a line number (yay!) but it doesn't tell you the file/function that the line is in (boo!).

That lack of function information a pretty big irritation if you are sitting on top of a codebase that is calling on a suite of functions in a source folder (or even a Jupyter notebook that has functions defined within it).

Is there a reason for this behaviour?

PS. You can do `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'raise')` but that doesn't explain why the warning it replaces is an uninformative debugging tool...

Comment: can you share the full trace? it usually tells you the exact instruction that causes the warning

Comment: `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'raise')` does show you the location of the warning. Copy and paste the full trace just as @Yuca suggested.

Comment: I know that the `pd.set_option('mode.chained_assignment', 'raise')` gives you better location information, the question is why the `settingWithCopyWarning` provides such an imprecise warning.  Seems needlessly inefficient and I am curious why it is done that way.